# Implement background gradient with Cocoapods "UIColor+uiGradients"

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiview

I am just starting out with Objective-C programming.

I am trying to add a cocoa pod with "UIColor+uiGradients" found here:
http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/UIColor+uiGradients/0.1.0/

I am adding the following code to ViewController.m as per the cocoadocs.org documentation:

```
UIColor *startColor = [UIColor uig_emeraldWaterStartColor];
UIColor *endColor = [UIColor uig_emeraldWaterEndColor];

CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient.frame = view.bounds;
gradient.startPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
gradient.endPoint = CGPointMake(view.frame.size.width, 0);
gradient.colors = @[(id)[startColor CGColor], (id)[endColor CGColor], nil];

[view.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
```

I am getting the following error message "Use of undeclared identifier 'view'; did you mean _view?"

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What, there was no line number with the error message???

Comment: (BTW, so how precisely is `view` defined?)

Comment: I haven't defined a view....I get 4 errors, where there is a view mentioned in the program, there is a semantic issue, undeclared view error.

Comment: So `view` is the view in your ViewController, which is a property defined in your superclass.  Except that, depending on the phase of the moon, the name of the associated instance variable may be `view` or `_view`.  Normally you should refer to this using the property name -- `self.view`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running an up-to-date version? DEBUG_TOUCH is likely defined: Undefining it will likely stop the error.

Comment: Is this in the plist file or the header file for uicolor+uigradients.h ? I'm running Xcode 6.1 and version 0.1.0 of the cocoa pod. thanks